# lxc containers fail to autoboot in 14.04 trusty using 'lxc.start.auto = 1'

Tags: 14.04, autostart, lxc

In trusty 14.04 containers fail to autoboot despite all settings being set as 14.04 requires.
They show all as STOPPED

I have correctly configured 2 LXC containers:

```
calypso  
encelado
```

They run perfectly if I run
`sudo lxc-autostart`

then
`sudo lxc-ls --fancy`
results in:

```
ubuntu@saturn:/etc/init$ sudo lxc-ls --fancy 
NAME      STATE    IPV4           IPV6  AUTOSTART 

calypso   RUNNING  192.168.1.161  -     YES        
encelado  RUNNING  192.168.1.162  -     YES
```

The problem is trying to run them at boot.

I have at: `/var/lib/lxc/calypso/config`:

```
# Template used to create this container: /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download 
# Parameters passed to the template:
# For additional config options, please look at lxc.conf(5)

# Distribution configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf
lxc.arch = x86_64

# Container specific configuration
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/calypso/rootfs 
lxc.utsname = calypso

# Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
#lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.link = br0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:64:0b:6e  

# Assign static IP Address
lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.1.161/24
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 192.168.1.1 

# Autostart
lxc.start.auto = 1
lxc.start.delay = 5
lxc.start.order = 100
```

and I have 
`LXC_AUTO="false"`
as required
inside `/etc/default/lxc`:

```
LXC_AUTO="false"
USE_LXC_BRIDGE="false"  # overridden in lxc-net
[ -f /etc/default/lxc-net ] && . /etc/default/lxc-net
LXC_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT=120
```

Any idea on why the containers don't start at boot?
At reboot they are always in the STOPPED state:

```
ubuntu@saturn:~$ sudo lxc-ls --fancy
NAME      STATE    IPV4  IPV6  AUTOSTART 
calypso   STOPPED  -     -     YES       
encelado  STOPPED  -     -     YES
```

and then again they can be started manually, using `sudo lxc-autostart`

Comment: I noticed that creating a cron: '@reboot /usr/bin/lxc-autostart' it works. It seems Ubuntu 14.4 doesn't launch lxc-autostart at boot time as the documentation says, launching all the container with lxc.start.auto = 1

Answer (score 7):

You say:

> I have LXC_AUTO="false" as required inside /etc/default/lxc

That specifically tells the upstart job NOT to start any container. Just don't set it or set it to true and you'll notice containers starting at boot time.

Answer (score 4):

Check that LXC_AUTO is true in `/etc/default/lxc`

```
LXC_AUTO="true"
```

and add group parameter to your config

```
lxc.group = onboot
```

(or add `BOOTGROUPS=` with your setup to `/etc/default/lxc` )

I think that currently Ubuntus guide at [Ubuntu lxc](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html) incorrectly states that `LXC_AUTO` should be `false`. Also ignore `/etc/default/lxc` symlink requirement.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Manwe posted (which I found to be correct), I had to do some additional work because I am using the -P option on all my lxc commands to use a custom lxc path that's different from `/var/lib/lxc`. (In retrospect, if I did this again, I'd probably stick with the default location, but that is neither here nor there.)

Edit `/etc/default/lxc` and add at end:

```
OPTIONS="-P <lxcpath>"
```

Edit `/etc/init/lxc-instance.conf` and add

```
[ -f /etc/default/lxc ] && . /etc/default/lxc
```

to start of `pre-start` and `script` and add `$OPTIONS` after `lxc-wait` and `lxc-start`.

Like so:

```
pre-start script
        [ -f /etc/default/lxc ] && . /etc/default/lxc
        lxc-wait $OPTIONS -s RUNNING -n $NAME -t 0 && { stop; exit 0; } || true
end script

script
        [ -f /etc/default/lxc ] && . /etc/default/lxc
        exec lxc-start $OPTIONS -n $NAME
end script
```

Then it can be tested with:

```
sudo service lxc restart
sudo lxc-ls -P <lxcpath> --fancy
```